# Android Hybrid apps are not working after signing in with keystore

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I am using ionic3 on my application. The debug builds for development is working fine. But, after signing with keystore the app is not working. This is happening for production as well in android OS version >9(As we found out now with initial analysis).

We are not able to check the error also here because the builds are signed. :(

**software specification is**:

```
cordova 9.0.0
ionic 3
Android platform 8.0.0
Node 10.15.3
Angular 4

**plugin list:**
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib 3.3.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.19 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.8 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
info.protonet.imageresizer 0.1.1 "Image Resizer"
```

Please suggest for changes if needed. Even in production build, we have not published new build. The old build is getting this issue

Comment: Are you using any POJO classes to convert JSON to Classes?

Comment: no michael. this is cordova application for andriod.

Comment: please be clear when you say the app is not working? is it not running or is it showing a blank screen?

Comment: it is showing blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

If its working in debug mode but not after signed with KeyStore (release mode) then check if you are using minify or proguard or some other method or plugin to obfuscate your code. If you do then you have to go through every external library you have used and find their proguard rules and add them to your app.

Incase you are using any plugin for JSON mapping with class then you have to avoid this class to get obfuscate.

Or you can just disable obfuscation of code but not recommended.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199876/discussion-on-answer-by-xsheru-android-hybrid-apps-are-not-working-after-signing).

Answer (score 0):

we found out the solution. After updating the webview plugin to latest version solved the app stuck issue. But, still not able to find out root cause of it.

Comment: firstly, this should be a comment. Secondly, was it the ionic-webview?

Comment: yes...it fixed the issue..i am trying to find out root cause now.

Answer (score 0):

finally the root cause we found is the certificate got updated for service gateway and that intermediate certificate(trust anchor) was causing issue. we have trusted it manually from the android platform https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted and its fully functional now.

thanks everyone for support :)